# -webkit-keyframes and keyframes with comma?

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

Is it ok to use this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animationame, @keyframes animationame {
blablabla
blabla
bla
}
```

Instead of this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animationame {
blablabla
blabla
bla
}
@keyframes animationame {
blablabla
blabla
bla
}
```

Comment: No, the first one contains errors, so the entire block is ignored.

Comment: No, it won't work.

Comment: How you tried it ? Did it work ??

Comment: Maybe you need some preproccessor language like LESS or SCSS, you can make simple things and the compiler is that translate to complex things.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use this:

```
.animatedOut{
    from { .opacity(1); }
    to { .opacity(0); }
}

@keyframes animationOut {
    .animatedOut;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animationOut {
    .animatedOut;
}
@-ms-keyframes animationOut {
    .animatedOut;
}
@-moz-keyframes animationOut {
    .animatedOut;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is plain css?

Comment: is less that translates to plain css